# How to compensate for Paramiko rekey failures?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

**Short version:**

- Paramiko has a [known issue rekeying](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/49) during high-volume data
  transfers
- The referenced patch (now part of the dist) alleviates it by fiddling timing, but with high-volume transfers it is still possible to abort the connection if too much data flows before the rekey is completed
- The simplest workaround I see is to reference `paramiko.Packetizer.need_rekey()` and then block or sleep in my data transfer thread if it returns True

My questions:

1. **Any reference or examples of how to access `paramiko.Packetizer.need_rekey()` when what I have is a `paramiko.SSHClient()` object?**
2. **Any better suggestions for working around the problem?**

---

**Long version:**

Modern SSH sessions need to be rekeyed after a certain amount of time or data passed.  If a request for rekey has not been acted upon quickly enough - where "quickly enough" means too much time or too much data has passed since the rekey was requested - the connection is aborted as a secure protection mechanism.

Paramiko used to have a very narrow limit of 20 packets between rekey request and rekeying.  [This patch](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/pull/63) from 2012

> Increase(d) the limit of received packets between re-key request &
>   completion from 20 packets to 2**29 packets.

In my application, I'm transferring large (10-30 GB) data streams over a forwarded port using `paramiko.transport.open_channel`.  If I'm doing this between two hosts on the same LAN, it succeeds 100% of the time.  If the hosts are on different LANs, with incrementally higher latency, it begins to experience failures - let's say 50% of the time, but it could be more than that.

Needless to say, losing the SSH connection 25 GB into a 30 GB data transfer can be frustrating.

Using OpenSSH as the client, I do not have this problem, which is consistent with reports I've read that rekeying interoperability is problematic.  OpenSSH reportedly rekeys seamlessly with *itself*; with *others*... less so.  But I'm already using Paramiko to log into the remote host and run the necessary commands to initiate the data transfer; having to open a separate OpenSSH session just to forward the port for the data is messy.

The correct fix seems to be that Paramiko should block or delay non-rekey packets while it gets rekeying out of the way - that seems to be the way OpenSSH handles it, although I haven't seen an authoritative confirmation of that.  But that's probably an ambitious change which would affect lots of people and take time.

The simple fix, as an interim measure, would be for my script to regulate itself.  I'd be happy to insert `sleep` calls or block the data transfer altogether while rekeying gets handled.  Without that massive data transfer going on in the background, the rekeying should easily finish within the deadline.

Paramiko provides a way to see if a rekey has been requested - `paramiko.Packetizer.need_rekey()`.  But I don't see how to call that within the context of my existing `SSHClient()` object.  For the `paramiko.transport.*` methods, I can use `paramiko.SSHClient().get_transport()` to create an object used to invoke them.  There does not appear to be a `paramiko.SSHClient().get_packetizer()` equivalent for gaining access to Packetizer methods.  There are no examples of Packetizer in the `demo/` code, and the `test_packetizer.py` file under `tests/` suggests that it's designed to be use as a raw interface instead of `SSHClient`.

So - to reiterate the questions from the short version above -

1. I think I could fix this by `sleep()`ing when I see that `paramiko.Packetizer.need_rekey()` is True, but I don't see how to access the `need_rekey()` method from my context of having an `SSHClient` object.  Any ideas?
2. Is there another solution to this problem that I should consider?

Any help is appreciated!

Version info FYI:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Apr  9 2015, 11:03:32)
[GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import paramiko
>>> paramiko.__version__
'1.15.2'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd still love to hear good answers to #2...

I found the answer to #1 via hacking and slashing: the `transport` object returned by `get_transport` includes a `packetizer` object which can be used to address the `need_rekey()` method:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Apr  9 2015, 11:03:32)
[GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import paramiko
>>> ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
>>> omkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file('./privkey.rsa')
>>> ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
>>> ssh.connect('gowenfawr.example.com', username='gowenfawr', pkey=omkey)
>>> transport = ssh.get_transport()
>>> transport.packetizer
<paramiko.packet.Packetizer object at 0x7fb121aa5650>
>>> transport.packetizer.need_rekey()
False
>>>
```

I updated my "data read" loop to check if `transport.packetizer.need_rekey()` was set, and if it was, to sleep using `time.sleep(1)`.  The following code prints out '.' every 1/80th of the data transfer progress and a 'Z' will be printed out whenever it pauses because a rekey has been requested:

```
track = 0
hash = int(size/80)
while True:
    r, w, x = select.select([chan], [], [])
    if chan in r:
        data = chan.recv(1024)
        if len(data) == 0:
            break
        os.write(fp[0], data)
        track = track + len(data)
        if transport.packetizer.need_rekey():
            sys.stdout.write('Z')
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(1)
        if track > hash:
            sys.stdout.write('.')
            sys.stdout.flush()
            track = 0
print ''
```

Which results in this sort of output

```
$ grabdata.py gowenfawr.example.com
target is gowenfawr.example.com
Found appropriate kernel version
Setting up data transfer
.....Z.....Z.....Z.....Z......Z.....Z.....Z.....Z.....Z......Z.....Z.....Z.....Z.....Z......Z.....Z...
Transfer complete!
$
```

Which tells me that rekeys are happening regularly (good, given the volume of data being transferred here) and I have not been able to reproduce the session abort failure over ~10 runs since the change.